# How can I avoid an event from firing on a parent element while clicking on the child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with some data inside. When I click on a  element, it adds a class `.active` to :

```
 $('#someId').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
        var target = $(this).find(".target");
        var prev = target.html();
        timeCell.html(target.data('prev'));
        timeCell.data('prev', prev);
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');

        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');

        }

    });
```

As you can see after clicking on tr, users could see some icons instead of previous data (.target) and I want them to click on icons ("prev") that call some other functions. But when the icons are clicked, a click on a parent element  is execute too. **How can I avoid this?**

**----**
***If anybody needs help in this case - here's the solution!***

```
 $('#someId').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
 var senderName = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (senderName === 'div') {
           //do some staff
        } else {
        var target = $(this).find(".target");
        var prev = target.html();
        timeCell.html(target.data('prev'));
        timeCell.data('prev', prev);
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');

        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');

        }

    });
```

Comment: In that case, simply use `e.stopPropagation()` will stop the click event from bubbling up to the parent `<tr>` element ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the click event on the parent `<tr>` element is being fired is due to event bubbling. You can stop the click event emitted within the child node from bubbling up (and being captured by the click event listener bound to the parent), is to simply call `event.stopPropagation()` in the child click event, i.e.:

```
$('#someId').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {

    // Stop click event from bubbling up to parent and getting captured
    e.stopPropagation();

    // Rest of the logic
    var target = $(this).find(".target");
    var prev = target.html();
    timeCell.html(target.data('prev'));
    timeCell.data('prev', prev);
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }

});
```

Comment: I saw this method in suggested post, while been writing a question. It didn't solve my problem. Don't know why..

Comment: What is the other click handler on the `<tr>` element?